# Change header and footer to only a group of pages

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to change the header and footer to only a group of pages in my document. I'm using the [`fancyhdr` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) with these settings:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\format@sec@number}[2]{{\normalfont\upshape#1}#2}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\format@sec@number{\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne\@chapapp\ \thechapter\, \fi}{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\format@sec@number{\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\z@\thesection\, \fi}{#1}}}
\makeatother

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
```

I would likt to not use these settings for some pages. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a job for the command `\fancypagestyle` from the `fancyhdr` package. You can define two styles and alter between them at your wish.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{style1}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{style 1 with thin line}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{style2}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{STYLE 2 WITH THICK LINE}
\fancyfoot[C]{= \thepage{} =}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
}

\pagestyle{style1}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\pagestyle{style2}

\lipsum[1-20]

\pagestyle{style1}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```