# How do I divide my current headerstyle into two similar headerstyles that I can alter between?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I was thinking of using the fancyhdr package to accomplish this task, [according to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91219/change-header-and-footer-to-only-a-group-of-pages), but I don't yet have the knowledge to get it done.

I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % If utf8 encoding
\usepackage{librecaslon}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{fetamont}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Include figures
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{alphalph,etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%%% PAGE LAYOUT 
%%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlrmarginsandblock{0.15\paperwidth}{*}{1} % Left and right margin
\setulmarginsandblock{0.2\paperwidth}{*}{1}  % Upper and lower margin
\checkandfixthelayout

%%% HEADER AND FOOTER 
%%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makepagestyle{standard} % Make standard pagestyle

\makeatletter                 % Define standard pagestyle
\makeevenfoot{standard}{}{}{} %
\makeoddfoot{standard}{}{}{}  %
\makeevenhead{standard}{\bfseries\thepage\normalfont\qquad\small\leftmark}{}{}
%\makeoddhead{standard}{}{}{\small\rightmark\qquad\bfseries\thepage}
\makeoddhead{standard}{}{}{%
    {\color{gray}\rule{1em}{1em}\hspace{0.2em}}%
    {\color{yellow}\rule{1em}{1em}\hspace{0.2em}}%
    {\color{blue}\rule{1em}{1em}\hspace{0.2em}}%
    {\color{brown}\rule{1em}{1em}\hspace{0.2em}}%
    {\color{black}\rule{1em}{1em}\hspace{0.2em}}%
    {\color{pink}\rule{1em}{1em}\hspace{0.2em}}%
    \hfill\small\rightmark\qquad\bfseries\thepage}
\makeheadrule{standard}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeatother                  %

\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{standard}{
    \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{ \quad }
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{ \quad }
    \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
    \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
    \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
    \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
    \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\makeatother                               %

\makepagestyle{chap} % Make new chapter pagestyle

\makeatletter
\makeevenfoot{chap}{}{\small\bfseries\thepage}{} % Define new chapter pagestyle
\makeoddfoot{chap}{}{\small\bfseries\thepage}{}  %
\makeevenhead{chap}{}{}{}   %
\makeoddhead{chap}{}{}{}    %
% \makeheadrule{chap}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeatother

\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{standard}               % Choosing pagestyle and chapter pagestyle
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{chap} %

%%% THE DOCUMENT
%%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{lipsum} % Just to put in some text

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter

    \mainmatter

%   \pagestyle{style1}
    \chapter{How to build a time machine}

    \lipsum[1-12]

%   \pagestyle{style2}
    \chapter{How to destroy a time machine}

    \lipsum[1-12]

%   \pagestyle{style1}
    \chapter{How to build a time machine}

    \lipsum[1-12]

    \backmatter

\end{document}
```

What I need to alter is the code located between **HEADER AND FOOTER** and **THE DOCUMENT**.

The code currently creates colored boxes inside the header of every odd page, and this is done for every page. My goal is to create one headerstyle that does not have those boxes while keeping the current style in the second headerstyle, and I was thinking of implementing the code below in order to get this done:

```
\fancypagestyle{style1}{ % without colored boxes

}

\fancypagestyle{style2}{ % with colored boxes

}
```

I need both headers to be identical, apart from one not having those boxes while the other does have them.

Comment: You are using `memoir`'s method of setting header and footer styles. Just make two of them, one with colours and the other without, then call them as you need them.

Comment: I got it, thanks. How should I mark this question as answered - should I reply to it myself? Or do I edit out the fancyhdr?

Comment: @user3776022: `memoir` comes with its own sophisticated way of setting the headers and footers, I don't think that you should bring disturbance into the scheme with `fancyhdr`. As far as I know, `memoir` and `fancyhdr` are not really compatible.